# Local GPO not reflecting updated reg value

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, gpo

I am trying to setup a way to script GPO settings on a local machine that is not domain joined/standalone. I was thinking I could script the registry changes and it would reflect in gpedit, but that doesn't seem to be the case. No matter what I do to the registry, the reflected policy does not show when I close/open gpedit again. gpupdate does not do anything, and if I log off/back on, whatever the policy is set to overrides the registry setting I made. I am using powershell to do this, but the scripting portion isn't as much of a question at this time. I want to know if there is a way to get the gpo to reflect/update based off of the registry, and not the other way around?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Please see [this](https://serverfault.com/a/875919/547416) helpful answer. You can use the [PolicyFileEditor](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PolicyFileEditor/3.0.0) powershell module.

https://serverfault.com/questions/848388/how-to-edit-local-group-policy-with-a-script